# Break statement giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript

I am using the break statement and I want it to, when I enter 3, break and log "I am breaking."

But somehow it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
var enteredNumber=window.prompt("Enter A Value");
for (i=enteredNumber; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (enteredNumber===3) {
        console.log('I am breaking');

        break;
    }   
}
```

**It dosen't show any result.**
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are using strict comparison so it wont accept 3 as number.

```
var enteredNumber=window.prompt("Enter A Value");
        for (i=enteredNumber; i <= 10; i++) {

            if (i==3) {
                alert('i am breaking');

                break;
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a datatype problem. The value entered is a String and you are comparing it to a number. Try this:

```
var enteredNumber=+window.prompt("Enter A Value");
    for (i=enteredNumber; i <= 10; i++) {

        if (enteredNumber===3) {
            console.log('i am Breaking');

            break;
        }

    }
```

Notice the little + sign? That says to interpret the value entered as a number. Now the condition `enteredNumber ===3` is true when you enter 3.

Comment: "This is a datatype problem" --- not only that - the whole loop is pointless.

Comment: There will be no the second step though.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the loop at `3`, your if statement should look at variable `i` and not at `enteredNumber` because you're looping `i` and not `enteredNumber`

```
        if (i===3) {
            console.log('i am Breaking');

            break;
        }
```